# How to use two conditionals in a loop in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

This is the first small PowerShell script I'm writing so forgive me if this is a very simple question.

I am attempting to loop through some directories in the current directory and do something in each one. I want catch the ones whos dirname starts with "abc*" and "alphabet*".

This works for catching just the abc* directories:

```
foreach ( $f in Get-ChildItem -Filter abc*) {
   do something
}
```

but when I try to add a second filter to catch the alphabet* dirs it does not work.

I've also tried:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {if {($_.Name -Contains "abc") -or ($_.Name -Contains "alphabet")} { "it worked!"}}
```

How can I loop use two conditionals in a loop?

Comment: `-Include` might work, `Get-ChildItem -Include abc*, alphabet*`, but also you can loop through the filters: `'abc*', 'alphabet*' | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem -Filter $_ -Directory }`

Comment: The `-Contains` operator is meant to search for a value in an **array**. This differs from the string method `.Contains()` that looks for a matching substring in a string. You could use the regex `-match` operator: `Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'abc|alphabet' }`. (the `|` in there is the regex `OR`)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*abc*" -or $_.Name -like "*alphabet*"}
```